# li onClick function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following files in the order it stands:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/music.js"></script>
```

in main.js I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('.song').click(function() {
        $('.footer').show('easeInExpo');
        audioPlayer(band, album, track);
    });
});
```

In music.js where the `audioPlayer function` is called:

```
function audioPlayer(band, album, track) {
 var audio = new Audio; //Class
audio.src = 'music/' + band + '/' + album + '/' + track + '.mp3';
audio.play();
}
```

The code that calls the function:

```
<li class="song" onlick="javascript:audioPlayer('Band name', 'Album name', 'Track name');"></li>
```

If I run this code I get:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: band is not defined`

I have also tried to do the following with main.js:

```
$('.song').click(function(band, album, track) {
    $('.footer').show('easeInExpo');
    audioPlayer(band, album, track);
});
```

Which gives me: `GET http://localhost/media/music/[object%20Object]/undefined/undefined.mp3 404 (Not Found)`

Does anyone knows how to fix the `audioPlayer() function` problem?
Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, why are you mixing two “models” of event handling here (event binding via jQuery vs. “old-school” event handler HTML attributes)? I’d strongly suggest you stop doing that, it is likely to lead to problems. // You are calling `audioPlayer(band, album, track)` inside your document.ready handler – but there are no such variables defined in that scope, so it is only natural you get that error. What’s that call supposed to be good for anyway, when you are calling that function – _with_ appropriate parameters – directly from the element (`onclick`) already …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onlick="javascript:audioPlayer('Band name', 'Album name', 'Track name');"` code within the li is set up to provide these parameters, but it's not spelled correctly `onlick` should be `onclick`.

And there is also a click event listener which is executed outside of that `onclick` function so it doesn't get any parameters.

---

One solution would be to change your li's to use data-attributes:

```
<li class="song" data-band="Band name" data-album="Album name" data-track="Track name"></li>
```

then modify the click listener as follows:

```
$('.song').click(function() {
    $('.footer').show('easeInExpo');
    var data = $(this).data();
    audioPlayer(data.band, data.album, data.track);
});
```

Comment: well it turns out that adding the `c` to onclick was enought to make it work. TY

Comment: You still have two event listeners attached to every `<li>`... If you don't want to change the them, then remove the jQuery `click` event binding. Although, using data-attributes is a better solution since it separates the code from your HTML; this makes it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the onClick listener on the li tag. Instead, in the jQuery, find the band, album, and track names and call the function. Something like this:

```
$('.song').click(function(band, album, track) {
$('.footer').show('easeInExpo');

var band = $(this).data("band");
var album = $(this).data("album");
var track = $(this).data("track");
audioPlayer(band, album, track);
});
```

And add the data attributes on the li:

```
<li class="song" data-band="test band" data-album="test album" data-track="test track"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem with with the OnClick function:

Please try to change :

```
<li class="song" onlick="javascript:audioPlayer('Band name', 'Album name', 'Track name');"></li>
```

To:

```
  <li class="song" onclick="audioPlayer(\'' + bandname + ','+ albumName +','+ Track + \')"></li>
```

I am not sure if this is the only problem, but if it is you should really be doing this with proper DOM methods though.

```
var liElement = document.createElement('li');
liElement.addClass("song");
liElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
    audioPlayer(song.band,song.name,song.track);
});

​document.body.appendChild(liElement);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, your

```
<li class="song" onlick="javascript:audioPlayer('Band name', 'Album name', 'Track name');"></li>
```

not works, reason is spelling mistake.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.song').click(function() {
    $('.footer').show('easeInExpo');
    audioPlayer(band, album, track);
});});
```

will not work, because you are not specified what are band, album, track in the scope. 
You will not require the jquery part if you are use 'onclick' in your li tag.